# Who is in charge of the monster association, Gyoro Gyoro or Orochi?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the One Punch Man manga,

> Orochi is said to be the king of the monsters, but Gyoro Gyoro tells to (Phoenix I believe?) that he created Gyoro Gyoro.

Who is in charge of the monster association, Gyoro Gyoro or Orochi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Orochi](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Orochi) is the leader of the association. [Gyoro Gyoro](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Gyoro_Gyoro) is just a close adviser. While he may have created him, that does not immediately mean he is more powerful or the immediate leader. Remember those two brothers in OPM, where the weak older brother created a really powerful and gigantic younger brother via his serum?